# MS Access VBA loop through query and rename files

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query that contains two fields, 'From' and 'To'.  The from and to hold data that has the complete files paths of files that I want to rename.  How do I loop through the query and actually rename the files?  This is my code below but it's not working:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 Dim db As Database
 Dim strSQL As String

 Set db = CurrentDb

 strSQL = "select * from qryImagesToRename"

 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

 Do While Not rs.EOF

    Name .Fields("From") as .Fields("To")

    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Where am I going wrong? - I receive a Compile error "Expected user-defined type, not project" and it highlights the line:

```
Dim db As Database
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What exactly do you mean by *"it's not working"*? Do you get an error? (Oh, and you probably wanted to write `rs.Fields` instead of `.Fields`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the recordset object:

```
Name rs.Fields("From").Value As rs.Fields("To").Value
```